# Gerrit API - Submit Not Permitted

Tags: git, api, gerrit

I am trying to use APIs given by Gerrit. I have a commit in Gerrit that is ready to be submitted. Through given APIs, I try to submit that particular change into repository.

I can see some APIs (like getting Project Details, commit details) work. So this means authentication is done properly by me. But then , as said above, I have a commit ready to submit and I want to do the same via API.

There is Submit API (POST /changes/{change-id}/submit). My constructed API Url is "localhost:8080/a/changes/Ie4b9df572a88b69faa4a6376582f6acca26e0407/submit". When I try to run this API url, (testing through Postman) I get error as "submit not permitted". I run gerrit in localhost to test this.

Can I know what I am missing here or what is the wrong I did here to execute this?

Comment: What is the Gerrit version? It's seems like a permission issue... the user running the REST command has permission to submit, right?

Comment: Hi Marcelo,. I am able to submit the commit through GERRIT's UI. Not happening through REST API

Comment: Missed to add one more point. I use Gerrit 2.12.5 version.

How to check whether user running REST has permission to Submit?

Comment: Are you not using the same user in Gerrit UI and REST? You can check the permissions either by log in to Gerrit web using the REST user or by using the "List Access Rights" REST endpoint (see details here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-access.html).